# Scheduling a second notification if first is ignored in swift (or completing any action if notification is ignored)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

So I have an app currently on the app store that schedules 10 notifications in advance assuming you miss one you will still get a second chance or ten. Now before you think I will be bothering the person, the notification is very important to the functionality of the app and really is the main purpose. The app was built for iOS 7 so at that time there was no "handleActionWithIdentifier" which can, from my understanding, complete actions for the app even if it is closed depending on the users response to the notification. This update was very helpful for the app as it eliminates part of my problem of having to open the app to respond to the notification (the notifications ask the user a question and depending on the answer, completes something).

The problem that remains is detecting if the notification was missed, how would I make another notification appear, for example the next day, if the notification is dismissed or ignored. I have searched this on google and stack overflow and from my understanding all previous questions have been asking how to detect if the notification was missed one the app is opened which I do not need.

At this point, I can properly run code if the user responds to the notification by pressing one of the options on the notification by this :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, withResponseInfo responseInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        var userInfo = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
        userInfo["text"] = responseInfo[UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("text", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
```

as of right now, I am just taking textfield input and printing it but I could launch a second notification if I wanted. Is there a method to detecting when a notification is missed and scheduling another notification?

There is always a chance that it is still not possible to do what I want and I would just schedule 10 notifications in advance which seems sloppy and does not let me make the response as iterative.

TLDR; how do I detect and run code if a local notification is missed WITHOUT opening the app

BTW: if you have answers, swift is the preferred language

Comment: could you plz tell what approach(steps) did you take to solve this issue? even i have been going through this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a mixture of **Background Fetch** and **Some kind of timestamp test**.

> **For instance:**

When you schedule a notification you can keep some logic that would let you track if that notification was ignored or not. Maybe keep some data in `NSUserDefaults` holding which was the last **Notification** sent and **when** it should be launched by the O.S.

> One way could be to check for **that** timestamp:

If you launch this test after the moment in which it was supposed to launch (*and maybe a bit late, just in case the user see it but is still not ready to answer*) and you haven't still marked it as **not ignored**, then the user ***may*** have ignored or missed your notification.

> **This test should be able to be used in your AppDelegate.**

Then, **enable Background Fetch** capability in **Background Modes**.

> This will give some CPU time to your app (**when iOS thinks is a good
>   time for that**) and you can seize the opportunity ;-).

For being able to do that you will need to add proper function into your `AppDelegate` implementation:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
       // your code
    }
```

In this function's body, run your **"test for ignored notification"** and schedule new notifications if needed.

> **Don't forget to call `completionHandler` as soon as you finish your test!**

Comment: I think this will work, the only trouble I have is telling the device when to go through a "check". How, for example, would I ask the device to check for a missed notification in 10 minutes or so. I'm kind of confused on how often or how to control the fetches works.

Comment: welcome to iOS World! :D That is up to the system to decide, you just can tell it how often you would like to do it. But there's no guarantee that it will do a background fetch at that moment. As far as I know, the only option would be to rely on this mechanism, or do it the other way around: scheduling several notifications and removing the pending ones if the user entered your app.

Comment: Yea I think this is my only option so I decided to do a combination of both. I scheduled a couple notifications in advance and then did a fetch to schedule more if they were missed so it ends up being a little more reliable. Thanks for the answer!